# openstack nova-compute Failed to connect to libvirt

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

After interruption of power supply, error message shows up.

oslo_service.service [-] Error starting thread.: TypeError: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks
nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] Connection event '0' reason 'Failed to connect to libvirt: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks'
[image: nova.virt.libvirt.driver [-] Connection event '0' reason 'Failed to connect to libvirt: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks']

TRY1:
Restart openstack-nova and libvirtd, still the same.

TRY2:
Reinstall openstack-nova libvirt, everything is ok now.

Comment: Would need to see your nova-compute config most likely

Comment: @eandersson After reinstall openstack-nova libvirt, and use the same config, everything is ok now, thinks.

Comment: I would just like to point out to other readers that the "just reinstall it" approach is not recommended.  For a start, you are probably erasing many of the clues that could (should) be used to figure out what was broken and why.

Comment: Also, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).